# Mysql relacion de una a muchos(traer la informacion al mismo tiempo)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

si tengo una relacion de una a muchas tablas
son 5 tablas la principal y la otras 4 tablas

si tengo que traer la informacion de las 5 tablas  al mismpo tiempo cual seria la manera correcta de hacerlo??
lo que hize fueron 5 procedimientos almacenados distintos
4 inner join por separado para las 4 tabla  y otro select de la tabla principal
esta bien o hay manera mas optima de hacerla
como ven en la imagen la tabla departamento es la principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué información de las tablas necesitas retornar?. Dependiendo de la información a retornar, quizás, una única consulta sea suficiente. Algún ejemplo y algunos datos serían de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from departamento d 
inner join municipios m 
  on d.deptoID = m.deptoID
inner join ComidasTipicas ct
  on ct.deptoID = d.deptoID
  /*Aquí puedes agregar cualquier otra condición utilizando la cláusula And*/
inner join LugaresTuristicos lt
  on lt.deptoID = d.deptoID
inner join Pueblos p
  on p.deptoID = d.deptoID
```

Adicionalmente recomiendo que si vas a usar plural en el nombre de las tablas lo hagas en todas...